# snort rule to detect relay attempt not working

Tags: ids, snort

I am trying to detect a relay attempt on smtp server, but nothing gets logs when I test it out. The snort rule to detect a relay attempt which I tried using is:

```
alert tcp $SMTP_SERVERS 25 -> any any (msg: "Possible relay attempt"; flow:to_client; content:"Relay access denied"; sid:1000007;)
```

Comment: The snort rule tries to match a specific string. Have you checked that the mail server is even sending this string when somebody attempts to use the server as a mail relay?

Comment: Yes. tested it with telnet. The smtp server returns: 554 5.7.1 <test@gmail.com>: Relay access denied, but the rule with "Relay access denied" for content doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the checksum_mode to none in the snort.conf file (`config checksum_mode: none`) solves the problem and I can now see alerts for the relay rule in my log file.